# Slow FPS rate with more Bodies in the World

Tags: java, android, box2d, libgdx, game-engine

I am new to libgdx and I am learning it myself by modifying code in libgdx examples (gdx-test).

I modified Box2DTest and suprised to see that FPS drops from 60 to 3 in Android.

Code I changed:

1. PolyShape to CircleShape with radius 1
2. Modified the for loop condition from i<20 to i<120 (i.e created 120 shapes instead of 20).

**My question:**

1. How to improve the FPS?
2. Is there any limit to number of bodies that we can add to the World?
3. Most of the [demo game](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/demos) are not at all using Box2D. Why are they doing all physics calculations themselves instead of using Box2D? Will it improve performance?

Box2dTest.java is available [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/Box2DTest.java).

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you Brain. I will contribute as much as I can.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of asking on Stack Overflow for where your performance went, use tools or timers to *measure* where the time is being spent.  Then come to Stack Overflow armed with data to ask how to fix the problem.  I suspect you will discover that Box2d is not use any of the time, but its better to have data than to speculate.

For Libgdx on Android the [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) is a pretty suite of tools and is well integrated into Eclipse.  I would start with method profiling and heap tracking.

Comment: Yes, I started doing profiling. I will share the data and my findings as soon as I am done. Having said that, my questions are not only about performance but also about limitations of World class and why demo games are not using Box2D? Is that intentional?

Comment: Is there a way to trace an libGDX app on desktop? Sure i could always write a timestamp and so on but that would take a loot of time. Is there a "easy way" `?